# Will code after blocked async call continue in the same context if .ConfigureAwait(false) is used all the way beneath the blocking code?

Tags: c#, async-await

First, let me just say that I know you should use `await/async` for the whole stack, and not block async code. I know it leads to deadlocks.

Lets say I have this code:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var result = GetData().Result;

    var context2 = HttpContext.Current;
}

public async Task<string> GetData()
{
    // ... do stuff

    var result = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://stackoverflow.com").ConfigureAwait(false);

    var context1 = HttpContext.Current;

    // ... process result

    return processedResult; // processedResult could be whatever
}
```

In this scenario it the code has to wait for the HTTP request to finish. So `context1` will be `null` because the code runs on an arbitrary thread after the request has finished. That's because of the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` call and that it has to wait for the request to finish.

From reaserching and testing, it looks like `context2` will always have a value, never be `null`. From what I reason, that is logical. The `.Wait()`, `.Result`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will block the thread, then continue on it. However I haven't found explicit documentation that states this. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, or it is so basic that it's not really written anywhere. I mean, why would it suddenly change thread? I guess I am wondering because the code after `.ConfigureAwait(false)` runs on whatever other threads. Is there any chance `context2` could be `null`?

Comment: You seem to be asking "If I block a thread and then unblock, will the following code still be on the same thread?", which seems like an odd thing to think to ask.

Comment: Maybe this could be related to dependency injection. If you made Transient like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components), can you also Scoped and try it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess the uncertainty came from the fact that the async code continued in another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var result = GetData().Result;` will cause the current thread to be blocked until the asynchronous operation `GetData()` completes. When the thread resumes, the `HttpContext.Current` will have the same value as before, unless the code that is represented by the comment `// ... do stuff` has set it explicitly to `null` like this:

```
HttpContext.Current = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

> So context1 will be null because the code runs on an arbitrary thread after the request has finished.

It will be `null` because it runs on a thread pool context rather than the ASP.NET request context. The threads don't have anything to do with it.

> From reaserching and testing, it looks like context2 will always have a value, never be null.

Yes, blocking the current thread in that context will keep that same context, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719909/263693).

However, it is *also* never `null` if you do this:

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
  var result = await GetData();
  var context2 = HttpContext.Current;
}
```

And using `await` is the recommended pattern. Not just to avoid deadlocks, but also to make [maximum use of the thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net). To put it another way, blocking on asynchronous code negates **all** benefits of the asynchronous code in the first place. The whole point of asynchronous code is to free up a thread, but if the calling code blocks a thread until it's complete, then a thread is used up anyway.

In ASP.NET pre-Core, there are a handful of scenarios where blocking is unavoidable (child actions and MVC filters - but not WebApi filters). Those are the only places where I'd say blocking is acceptable; other than that you should use async all the way.

Comment: How would you define a "thread pool context"? I find myself not quite able to succinctly define it. The `HttpContext` object would be null, as opposed to in the ASP.NET request context, but isn't it more than that? Is it the `HttpContext` that keeps all the state for the ASP.NET request context?

Comment: @ptf: The thread pool context is the default context that just runs continuations on a thread pool. It's different than the ASP.NET request context; the ASP.NET request context also runs on a thread pool thread but runs with the request context. The request context includes `HttpContext.Current` and also some other things like thread culture and I believe impersonation (if you're using that). The thread pool context is pretty well defined; it's the ASP.NET request context that isn't defined anywhere.